# Save file names with Cyrillic letters from one textfile to other

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pattern-matching, codepages

maybe someone can help me...
I have a list (containing also cyrillic letters) like this (channels.txt):

```
#EXTINF:-1,5 канал Россия
http://95.189.57.162:1234/udp/233.7.70.6:5000
#EXTINF:-0,ТВ3
http://95.189.57.161:1234/udp/233.7.70.7:5000
#EXTINF:-1,ТНТ
rtmp://95.189.54.166:1234/udp/233.7.70.8:5000
#EXTINF:-2,Disney Channel
mms://95.189.52.146:1234/udp/233.7.70.9:5000
#EXTINF:-1,49 Канал
http://95.189.51.163:1234/udp/233.7.70.11:5000
```

The line begining with **#EXTINF:** gives the name of a TV channel. Channels are:

- 5 канал Россия
- ТВ3
- ТНТ
- Disney Channel
- 49 Канал

The next line is the link to that channel.

Which command or batch script could create a txt file for each channel of the list and put inside the corresponding link? For this example:

- 5 канал Россия.txt --> `http://95.189.57.162:1234/udp/233.7.70.6:5000`
- ТВ3.txt --> `http://95.189.57.161:1234/udp/233.7.70.7:5000`
- ТНТ.txt --> `rtmp://95.189.54.166:1234/udp/233.7.70.8:5000`
- Disney Channel.txt --> `mms://95.189.52.146:1234/udp/233.7.70.9:5000`
- 49 Канал.txt --> `http://95.189.51.163:1234/udp/233.7.70.11:5000`

I would really appreciate any help!
Many thanks!

Comment: What is the encoding scheme of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a IN ('chcp') DO SET /a CurrentCodePage=%%a 2>nul
CHCP 1251 >nul
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%a IN ('type file.txt') DO (
    SET "link=%%a"
    SET "channel=%%b"
    IF DEFINED channel (SET "fname=!channel!"
    ) ELSE (ECHO !link!)>"!fname!.txt"
)
CHCP %currentCodePage% >nul
```

---

`dir` output is with code page 850:

```
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                48 49 ?????.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 5 ????? ??????.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                46 Disney Channel.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 ??3.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 ???.txt
```

---

`dir` output is with code page 1251:

```
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                48 49 Канал.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 5 канал Россия.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                46 Disney Channel.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 ТВ3.txt
06/29/2013  08:38 AM                47 ТНТ.txt
```

For more information about cmd and code pages click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1259468/2098699).

Comment: +1. I think your code would be clearer if you exchange the `line1` and `line2` variable names or, better yet, rename `line1` to `link` (that appear in second line) and `line2` to `channel` (that appear in first line)... ;-)

Comment: @Aacini thanks for the tips. I did not think I get this to run :-)

Comment: Endoro, you are the greatest! Many thanks. It's working perfectly! I had some problems with the code page at the begining, but it was because my text file was UTF-8.